# Change a value from a JWT token header with Ktor pipeline

Tags: authentication, jwt, ktor

I have a big problem. I'm on a project, where the client requires the jwt to be encrypted.
So the company came up with a method that encrypts and decrypts a string as follows.

```
String.crypto() : String

String.decrypto(): String
```

When the user successfully logs in, a token is generated, for example:

```
 asdf.asdf.asdf (this token does not exist, it's just an example of a 3-part token)
```

and is then encrypted to

```
asdfghhjkl;asdsffgghhasfsfgg
```

accessing the login controller there is the following logic

```
post("/sign_in") { 
  val user = call.request<UserModel>()
  val login = service.login(user)
  if login != null
  val token = service.createToken()
  call.respond(200, token.encrypt() )
  else 
  call.respond(401)
}
```

In this way an encryption token is sent by the request.

When I'm receiving an encrypted token, I can't use it, because I need to decrypt it first.

I need to create a pipeline before the token is validated.
I'm trying as follows:

```
fun Application.configureJWT() {
  install(JWTPlugin)
}

private val JWTPlugin = createApplicationPlugin("JWTPlugin") {
  onCall { call ->
    val jwtEncrypted: String? = call.request.headers["Authorization"]
    val jwtDecrypted: String? = jwtEncrypted?.replace("Bearer", "")?.trim()?.decrypt()?.getOrThrow()
    jwtDecrypted?.let { call.response.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer $it") }
  }
}
```

I can't use

```
call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()
```

because the passed jwt is encrypted (asdfghhjkl;asdsffgghhasfsfgg) and does not follow the 3-part pattern

```
header. payload.signature
```

and when the JWT class tries to validate it it will throw an exception

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 1.
```

So my question is this: What's missing in my pipeline, after decrypting the jwt, following the next phases of the pipeline and being able to use the already decrypted jwt correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JWTAuthenticationProvider.Config.authHeader` method to redefine the parsing of the `Authorization` header:

```
jwt("auth-jwt") {
    authHeader { call ->
        val header = call.request.headers[HttpHeaders.Authorization] ?: return@authHeader null
        // Decode here

        try {
            parseAuthorizationHeader(header)
        } catch (cause: IllegalArgumentException) {
            null
        }
    }
/// ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Aleksei Tirman!