# Verifying jwt tokens with cookies in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor

I'm trying to make a JWT validation code block in Ktor. When the user sends a post request to the "/login" link and logs in, the response comes back. I create a jwt token, put it in a cookie, and send it to the client along with the response to the login request.

Afterwards, since this JWT token is already in the cookie on the client side, it also sends this token with every request it sends to the server.

I have no problems so far, but when I use any get or post request within the "authenticate { }" block, I cannot successfully verify this token and a 401 code is returned to the client every time. I'm sure the problem is in "install(Authentication) {}", but I couldn't find a resource on how to solve it.

Note: When I logged, I did not see that the code entered the "validate { credential ->}" block in any request.

```
            install(Authentication) {
                jwt("auth-jwt") {

                    realm = jwtRealm

                    val jwtAlgorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret)
                    verifier(
                        JWT.require(jwtAlgorithm)
                            .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
                            .build()
                    )

                    validate { credential ->
                        Log.i(TAG, "name: " + credential.payload.getClaim("name").asString())
                        if (credential.payload.getClaim("name").asString() != "") {
                            JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                    }

                    challenge { defaultScheme, realm ->
                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Token is not valid or has expired")
                    }
                }
            }


            post("/login") {
                try {
                    val requestData = call.receiveText()
                    val data: Map<String, String> = Gson().fromJson(requestData, Map::class.java) as Map<String, String>
                    val clientPassword = data["password"]
                    val serverPasswordEncrypted = sha256(DefaultServerData.defaultServerAuthPassword.toString())

                    if (clientPassword == serverPasswordEncrypted) {
                        val token = makeToken()
                        call.response.cookies.append(Cookie("auth_token", token, path = "/", httpOnly = true, maxAge = 3600)) // 1 hour
                        call.respond(ResponseDto(true, token))
                    } else {
                        call.respond(ResponseDto(false))
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, mapOf("password_status" to "Failed to process request: ${e.message}"))
                }
            }

    fun makeToken(): String {
        val jwtAlgorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret)
        return JWT.create()
            .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
            .withClaim("name", "example")
            .withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000000)) 
            .sign(jwtAlgorithm)
    }
```

Comment: The `Authentication` plugin expects the JWT token in the `Authorization` header. You can use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75016214/13963150 to read the token from the cookie.

Comment: When trying to use the solution you posted, I get the following error; "Default authentication configuration was not found. Make sure that you install Authentication plugin before you use it in Routing"

This error occurs when starting the server.

I tried it with 2.3.1 and the latest version 2.3.4, the result is the same.

I'm pretty sure the "install(Authentication){}" block is before the "routing {}" block. 

(One detail I didn't mention when asking the question; I'm using KTOR in a kotlin mobile app)

Code details are here: https://codeshare.io/r98Dp6  @AlekseiTirman

Comment: Either add the `"auth-jwt"` parameter to the `authenticate` call or remove this parameter from the `jwt` call.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify this parameter. It finally worked, thank you very much!

I would like to share my code for someone who wants to verify with cookies. Would you like to add it as an answer or should I add it? If you want to add the answer, the final version of my Authentication code; https://codeshare.io/r98Dp6 @AlekseiTirman

Comment: Please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Aleksey Tirman, here is the method to validate the JWT token on the server side, which I have stored in the client with cookies;

```
        install(Authentication) {
            jwt("auth-jwt") {
                realm = YOUR_JWT_REALM
                val jwtAlgorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(YOUR_JWT_SECRET_KEY)
                verifier(JWT.require(jwtAlgorithm).withIssuer(YOUR_JWT_ISSUER).build())

                authHeader { call ->
                    val cookieValue = call.request.cookies["YOUR_COOKIE_NAME_FOR_TOKEN"] ?: return@authHeader null
                    Log.i(TAG, " cookieValue: $cookieValue")

                    try {
                        parseAuthorizationHeader("Bearer $cookieValue")
                    } catch (cause: IllegalArgumentException) {
                        cause.message
                        null
                    }
                }

                validate { credential ->
                    if (credential.payload.getClaim("name").asString() == YOUR_JWT_ISSUER) {
                        JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                }
            }
        }


            authenticate("auth-jwt") {
                post("/example") {
                    val receivedToken = call.request.cookies["auth_token"]
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received token: $receivedToken")

                    call.respondText("Authenticated!")
                }
            }
```